# Google Maps with API Key not working in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have enabled the Google Maps API for website as you seen in picture below:

[image: Enabled Google API]

Then in my Google Console Credential, i only accept request from my web url as below:

[image: Google API Key]

The maps is working fine in my local development but not in my production which can be found at http://metros.events/e/entertainment/open-mic-night when you click at 'view maps' link.

Here is the code to show the Maps Iframe

```
<iframe width="100%" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/search?q=Taman%20Tun%20Dr%20Ismail%20Kuala%20Lumpur%20Federal%20Territory%20of%20Kuala%20Lumpur%20Malaysia&key=blablabla_evYvWvWYgjfprbiFmeG3Xiclk" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Any idea why its not working in my production

Comment: @robe007 it is there in the picture

Comment: Ok, have you tried with something like: `metros.events` and `*.metros.events`. I think you need to put both of them.

Comment: LOL i tried with your suggestion and its work! i thought when putting asterisk in front of the domain it will include all. thanks btw.. post it as answer below n i will mark it as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as I said before:

You need to put in the correct way your domain (**the referer**). It shoud be whitelisted as follows:

> metros.events
>
> *.metros.events